# Не работает запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delete Services from Services S inner join 
[RB/Services] RBS on RBS.ServiceId = S.ServiceId
join Recreation_Bases RB on RBS.RBId = RB.RBId
where RB.Location = 'Rivne';
```

И так тоже не работает:

```
delete from Services where Services.ServiceId in
(select Services.ServiceId from Services 
join [RB/Services] on [RB/Services].ServiceId = Services.ServiceId
join Recreation_Bases on [RB/Services].RBId = Recreation_Bases.RBId
where Recreation_Bases.Location = 'Rivne');
```

Что не так и как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что запрос из под SQL Server вы пытаетесь выполнить в MySQL.